# Show that if $U\cap A \neq \emptyset$, int$(M\backslash A) = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let (M, d) be any metric space. Given is that $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every nonempty open set U.

**Question:** How do I show that the int$(M\backslash A) = \emptyset$, where int(X) denotes the interior of X.

I've tried proof by contradiction: assume that int$(M\backslash A) \neq \emptyset$ $\Rightarrow$ there exists at least one point $x \in M \backslash A$ with $B_\epsilon(x) \subset M\backslash A$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. I'm sure that I now should be able to point out that this would mean that there's a open set U with $U \cap A = \emptyset$, which would result in a contradiction, but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you know about $B_e(x)$? Is it open, closed, both,...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is an open set
2. $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq M\setminus A\iff B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A=\emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your proof itself.

If $B_\epsilon(x) \subset M \backslash A$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and some $x \notin A$, then $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A = \emptyset$,while $B_\epsilon(x)$ is an open set, by the definition of the metric topology.

That gives a contradiction, as then, $B_\epsilon(x)$ is an open set that has empty intersection with $A$. This completes the proof.

Now, just to try to give you a different approach:

Try to prove the following : if $\overline A$ is the closure of $A$, then $\operatorname{int }(M \backslash A) \subset (\overline A)^c$ (this would be true in general). Then, show that $\overline A = M$ with the given information. Finally, conclude.